# SQL Server CASE Statement Evaluate Expression Once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I may be missing something obvious! Thanks in advance for any help.

I am trying to use a CASE statement in an inline SQL Statement. I only want to evaluate the expression once, so I am looking to put the expression in the CASE section, and then evaluate the result in each WHEN. Here is the example:

```
    SELECT
         MyTable.ColumnA, 
         CASE DateDiff(d, MyTable.MyDate, getDate())    
                WHEN <= 0 THEN 'bad'
                WHEN BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN 'reasonable'
                ELSE 'good'
         END as MyCalculatedColumn,
         MyTable.SomeOtherColumn
```

I know I can do this:

```
 CASE 
        WHEN DateDiff(d, MyTable.MyDate, getDate()) <= 0 THEN 'bad'
        WHEN DateDiff(d, MyTable.MyDate, getDate()) BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN 'reasonable'
        ELSE 'good'
 END
```

But in my first example, SQL does not seem to like this statement:

```
WHEN <= 0 THEN 'bad'
```

Note that the statement is inline with other SQL, so I can't do something like:

```
DECLARE @DaysDiff bigint
SET @DaysDiff = DateDiff(d, MyTable.MyDate, getDate())  

 CASE @DaysDiff    
        WHEN <= 0 THEN 'bad'
        WHEN BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN 'reasonable'
        ELSE 'good'
 END
```

My actual DateDiff expression is much more complex and I only want to maintain its logic, and have it evaluated, only once.

Thanks again...

Comment: You need to use a scalar value when using the format `CASE expression WHEN value THEN ...`. you'll have to use `CASE WHEN Boolean Expression THEN...` instead.

Comment: `CASE expression WHEN value` can only do an equality check

Comment: Yes, codeulike, this seems to be the limitation I am hitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` for this purpose:

```
 SELECT MyTable.ColumnA, 
        (CASE WHEN day_diff <= 0 THEN 'bad'
              WHEN BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN 'reasonable'
              ELSE 'good'
         END) as MyCalculatedColumn,
        MyTable.SomeOtherColumn
FROM MyTable CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DateDiff(day, MyTable.MyDate, getDate()))) v(day_diff)
```

`APPLY` is a very handy way to add calculated values into a statement.  Because they are defined in the `FROM` clause, they can be used in `SELECT`, `WHERE`, and `GROUP BY` clauses where column aliases would not be recognized.

Comment: Wow, Gordon, this worked like a champ. This is extremely useful information for this situation and others I often face. I had several other INNER JOINS and a few LEFT JOINS with aliases that were also used as variables in the DateDiff, but by simply putting the CROSS APPLY at the end of all the joins, it worked perfectly. I looked at the execution plan, and as you suggested, since this is essentially in the FROM clause, it is evaluated only once and available to every row. Brilliant! Thank you so much.

Comment: I hadn't seen `VALUES` before, interesting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem. `CASE expression WHEN value` can only do an equality check

You could try using a CTE (Common Table Expression), do everything except the case statement in the CTE and then put the CASE in the final SELECT at the end. I'm not sure whether it will prevent the expression being evaluated twice - thats kindof the optimisers problem, not yours (thats how I like to think about it)

```
     WITH cteMyComplexThing AS(
            SELECT MyTable.ColumnA, 
                DateDiff(d, MyTable.MyDate, getDate()) as ComplexThing,
                MyTable.SomeOtherColumn
            FROM MyTable
     ) 
     SELECT
          ColumnA, 
          CASE    
            WHEN ComplexThing <= 0 THEN 'bad'
            WHEN ComplexThing BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN 'reasonable'
            ELSE 'good'
           END as MyCalculatedColumn,
          SomeOtherColumn
     FROM cteMyComplexThing
```

Comment: That's a really good idea. Worse-case, it allows me maintain the complexity of the DateDiff function in a single location. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The WHEN clause in a CASE statement needs both sides of the condition.  <=0 cannot stand by itself.

```
 CASE @DaysDiff    
    WHEN ? <= 0 THEN 'bad'
    WHEN BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN 'reasonable'
    ELSE 'good'
 END
```